# TextBox не изменяет свойство

Tags: c#, wpf

TextBox находится в GroupBox, который находится в вложенном в ScrollViever Grid'е. Перепробовал уже все, так как количество стержней динамически меняется нет возможности задать через Xaml

```
class RodTextBox : TextBox
{
    public RodTextBox(string text,string propertyName, Rod rod)
    {
        Text = text;
        TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
        addBinding(propertyName ,rod);
        DataContext = rod;
        GotFocus += clearTextOnFocus;
    }
    public void addBinding(string propertyName, Rod rod )
    {

        Binding myBinding = new Binding($"{propertyName}");
        myBinding.Source = rod;
        myBinding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.LostFocus;
        myBinding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
        SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, myBinding);
    }
    public void clearTextOnFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Text = String.Empty;
    }
   
}
class Rod : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public Rod (int number, int sqare,int length,int elastic)
    {
        Number = number;
        Sqare = sqare;
        Length = length;
        Elastic = elastic;
    }
    int _Number;
    int _Sqare;
    int _Length;
    int _Elastic;
    public int Number
    {
        get
        {
            return _Number;
        }
        set
        {
            _Number = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Number");
        }
    }
    public int Sqare
    {
        get
        {
            return _Sqare;
        }
        set
        {
            _Sqare = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Sqare");
        }
    }
    public int Elastic
    {
        get
        {
            return _Elastic;
        }
        set
        {
            _Elastic = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Elastic");
        }
    }
    public int Length
    {
        get
        {
            return _Length;
        }
        set
        {
            _Length = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Length");
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
```

Comment: `Перепробовал уже все` - кроме нормальных привязок, и использования XAML по назначению, да?) Почему вы вообще привязываетесь через код? Почему вы используете `Rod` класс (который по сути ViewModel слой, то есть слой с подготовленными данными (я сейчас не про MVVM) в классе контрола напрямую, когда ваш контрол должен быть универсальным, подходящим под все данные..? Вот есть, к примеру `<TextBox />`, он же не просит некий класс для своей работы? Нет. Он получает данные через `DependencyProperty` (например `Text = "..."`, где `...` - любое значение, взятое из любых мест). Так почему у вас не так?

Comment: Насколько я понимаю задать переменное количество TextBox можно только программно, поэтому пришлось прибегнуть к этому варианту. Буду благодарен , если направите на вариант более правильной организации такого типа. Нельзя создавать из общих классов узкоспециализированных наследников?

Comment: `задать переменное количество TextBox` - это называется коллекция, за вывод коллекций в WPF отвечает `ItemsControl`, либо основанные на нем (`ListBox` например). Делайте список объектов (НЕ КОНТРОЛА!), например `public List<int> Items { get; } = new() { 1, 2, 3 };`, задавайте `DataContext` окну на класс, где будет это свойство, ну и привязывайте `<ItemsControl ItemSource = "{Binding Items}">Нужный вид</ItemsControl>`. Все, на экране у вас 1, 2, 3 с нужным вам видом, хоть `TextBox`, хоть `Image`, хоть что либо еще... Я думаю вы поняли, что ваш код - по сути ерунда, которой не должно быть.